# Save query in different variables

Tags: c#

Need some ideas how to do it. I want to put and return values from multiple request into 3 different variables.

```cs
public int VerificationValid(long userId, TimeSpan periodMinute, TimeSpan periodDay, TimeSpan periodWeek)
{
    Period period;
    using (IDbConnection dbConnection = Connection)
    {
        dbConnection.Open();

        period = dbConnection.Query<Period>("SELECT (SELECT (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM verifications WHERE UserId=@UserId AND created > now() - interval PeriodMinute),SELECT COUNT (*) FROM verifications WHERE UserId=@UserId AND created > now() - interval PeriodDay )SELECT COUNT (*) FROM verifications WHERE UserId=@UserId AND created > now() - interval PeriodWeek;",
                new {UserId = userId, PeriodMinute=periodMinute, PeriodDay=periodDay, PeriodWeek=periodWeek})
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }

    return period.periodDay;
    //Want to do this but its wrong
    return period.periodMinute;
    return period.periodWeek;
}
```

This is Period class

```cs
public class Period
{
    public int periodMinute { get; set; }

    public int periodDay { get; set; }

    public int periodWeek { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Just do `return period` and make the return type of your function `Period` instead of `int`.

Comment: return type of VerificationValid method must be Period class. Then `return period;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just return the Period class:

```
public Period VerificationValid(long userId, TimeSpan periodMinute, TimeSpan periodDay, TimeSpan periodWeek)
{
    Period period;
    using (IDbConnection dbConnection = Connection)
    {
        dbConnection.Open();

        period = dbConnection.Query<Period>("SELECT (SELECT (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM verifications WHERE UserId=@UserId AND created > now() - interval PeriodMinute),SELECT COUNT (*) FROM verifications WHERE UserId=@UserId AND created > now() - interval PeriodDay )SELECT COUNT (*) FROM verifications WHERE UserId=@UserId AND created > now() - interval PeriodWeek;",
                new {UserId = userId, PeriodMinute=periodMinute, PeriodDay=periodDay, PeriodWeek=periodWeek})
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }

    return period;
}
```

If you want to have three different values (I can't understand why exactly) you can use `Tuples`.